# Countering the Royal Giant

Tags: clash-royale

How do I counter a Royal Giant? My current deck consists of Giant, Archers, Tombstone, Zap, Fireball, Baby Dragon, Mega Minion and Mini Pekka.

Should I be using Mini Pekka or Inferno Dragon or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

In [another answer I provided](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286665/how-can-i-take-out-the-barbarians-in-clash-royale/286677#286677), I linked to a page where you can find strategy (including counters) to each card. [Here is the link](http://clashroyalearena.com/cards).

For the Royal Giant they suggest a Minion Horde or Skeleton Army.  In my experience I have noticed barbarians are also pretty good at taking out the Royal Giant (and will survive most spells that would take out the Minion Horde and Skeleton Army).  I don't use any of those and instead opt for the Lumberjack.

I notice none of these cards are in your deck, however.  For your deck (if  you are unable/unwilling to make changes), I would recommend using the Mini-Pekka, especially if you can get the Royal Giant distracted by your Tombstone.  Once you know your opponent has the Royal Giant, save those two cards to counter it (but expect the Royal Giant to have back-up!).  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Well first use the Tombstone to distract the Royal Giant for a couple shots. When the Tombstone is destroyed, it will spawn 4 extra Skeletons that will slowly chip at the Royal Giant. Then deploy the Mini Pekka and have your spells ready to counter any counters to your Mini Pekka.

Of course, Inferno Tower/Dragon would be excellent unless they have the Zap, which resets the damage. If using the Inferno Tower, make sure the Royal Giant is in its range because a Royal Giant's range is larger than the Inferno Tower. Swarms such as Skeleton Army or Minion Horde would do quick work unless countered by Zap, Arrows, or Fireball. Barbarians work as well unless there's a Bomber.